# How to have double curly braces in Python using format()?

Tags: python, format

I have the following string:

```
High CPU on app_name:{app_name}  {{host.name}} / {{host.ip}}
```

I would like to render it with format to replace app_name with actual application name.

```
'- name: High CPU on app_name:{app_name}  {{{host.name}}} / {{{host.ip}}}'.format(app_name='test')
```

This results in a key error:

KeyError: 'host'

Is there a way to print {{ something }} when I would like to use format on the string?

Solution is to have everything in curly brackets variables. I am not sure if this can be done any other way.

```
'High CPU on app_name:{app_name}  {{{{{host_name}}}}} / {{{{{host_ip}}}}}'.format(app_name='test', host_name='host.name', host_ip='host.ip')
```

Result:

```
'High CPU on app_name:my_app  {{host.name}} / {{host.ip}}'
```

Comment: `- name: High CPU on app_name:{app_name}  {{{{host.name}}}} / {{{{host.ip}}}}'.format(app_name='test')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format string needs a pair of braces for *each* literal brace.

```
>>> '{foo}'.format(foo=3)
'3'
>>> '{{{foo}}}'.format(foo=3)
'{3}'
>>> '{{{{{foo}}}}}'.format(foo=3)
'{{3}}'
```

If you *only* want braces around something, then it has to be an even number of braces:

```
>>> '{hi} {{foo.bar}}'.format(hi=3)
'3 {foo.bar}'
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem that Python tries to lookup host as a key. '{hi} {{{{{host.name}}}}} / {{{{{host.ip}}}}}'.format(hi='hi') KeyError: 'host'

Comment: This happens because it tries to treat it as a variable. I think I need to stop format to treat it as a variable and start to treat it as a string. Not sure it is possible

Comment: That has nothing to do with the braces; you haven't specified a value for `host` in the call to `format`.

Comment: What do you want the results to actually *be*? You have an odd number of braces, so yes, you have a field that `format` will try to replace. If you *only* want literal braces in the result, you need an *even* number of braces in the string.

Comment: Updated the question. Essentially it is about how to stop format() handling something as a variable.

Comment: Finally I get it! Thanks.